# $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n $ for $ a_n = \frac{2n^{2n}}{(2n)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been trying to find the limit of this sequence $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n^{2n}}{(2n)!}$. Firstly I've expanded the expression and found this:
$$\frac{2n}{2n}.\frac{2n}{2n-1}.\frac{2n}{2n-2}\dots\frac{2n}{n+1}.\frac{(2n)^n}{n!}$$
Since the first n terms are greater than one, I've concluded $\frac{2n^{2n}}{(2n)!}>\frac{(2n)^n}{n!}$. However, it didn't help me to find the limit. Secondly, I've realized that the first n terms are less than two; therefore first n terms must be smaller than $2^n$. I've concluded $$\frac{2n^{2n}}{(2n)!}<2^n.\frac{(2n)^n}{n!}=\frac{(4n)^n}{n!}$$ which is a sequence similar to the initial sequence. Shortly I couldn't go further. How can I find the limit of this sequence?

Comment: Stirling's formula come to mind. Can you use that?

Comment: That seems to very rapidly go to infinity. Perhaps you were wanting a nth root?  $\quad$ Also, do you want the numerator to be $(2n)^{2n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: As you've already shown:

$$\frac{(2n)^{2n}}{(2n)!} \ge \frac{(2n)^n}{n!}.$$

But
$$\frac{(2n)^{2n}}{n!} \ge \frac{2n}{n} \times \frac{2n}{(n-1)} \times \cdots \times \frac{2n}{1}$$
$$ \ge \underbrace{2 \times 2 \times \cdots \times 2}_{\text{$n$ times}} = 2^n.$$

Thus, for each $n \ge 2$:

$$\frac{(2n)^{2n}}{(2n)!} \ge 2^n,$$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2^n$ is $\infty$, so $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(2n)^{2n}}{(2n)!} = \infty$$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Claim: $ \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \infty $.

Proof:

Note that $a_n > b_n = \frac{n^n}{n!}$, so it is enough to show that  $ \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \infty $.

Prove that $b_n$ is an increasing sequence, for example prove $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}>1$. Thus, by Monotone Convergence Theorem $b_n$ either converges to a limit $l \in \mathbb{R}$ or $ \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \infty $. Suppose the former holds.

Key step: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{m+1}{m} \right)^m= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+ \frac{1}{m} \right)^m=e$.

However by the algebra of limits, we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=l/l=1$, hence a contradiction.